# How do catch the Enter Event on a non-input element in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a confirm Button, that should also be triggered by an Enter-Event.

Basically, I was hoping that this could work:

```
<someComponent @keyup.enter="handleConfirm" />
...
methods: {
  handleConfirm(event) {
       console.log("works") 
  }
}
```

But it doesn't. Apparently, this approach only works with input fields.

How can I listen to a keyup Event in Vue on any element/component?

**EDIT**
To clarify: Any element/component even out of focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event already triggers with the ENTER key (it also triggers with Space in some browsers, like Chrome for desktop). So, your code only needs a @click="callEvent" and everything works well since the focus is already on the button

If you want that any ENTER triggers the button even if it isn't with focus, you should bind the event to the window object, which can be made inside the mounted handler

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    callEvent() {
      console.log("Event called");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) { 
        app.callEvent();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button>Enter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It is the latter case, so any Enter Event. It works, so you have the answer to technically solve the problem. Having said that: Isn't there a way for listen to the enter Event without using window but using vue itself? If not I will mark your answer as the correct one in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
`<someComponent @keyup.enter="handleConfirm($event)" />`

```
methods: {
  handleConfirm(event) {}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Not sure, maybe you assumed I didn't have a method, but I got one of course. I edit the question to clarify that.